# Why isn't this embedded sound file playing?

Tags: actionscript-3, audio, air, embed, flash

I've been going through a few tutorials, trying to find how to embed audio files and play them in AS3, and they tend to show examples which are very similar.  However when I try to use these examples, nothing is played.  My mp3 file will be embedded successfully, all the lines of code will execute sucessfully, but there will just be no sound.  Take the following code, for instance:

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.media.Sound;

    public class Main extends Sprite 
    {
        [Embed(source='/../lib/Kalimba.mp3')]        
        private var MySound : Class;         
        private var sound : Sound;

        public function Main():void 
        {
            if (stage) init();
            else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        }

        private function init(e:Event = null):void 
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
            sound = (new MySound()) as Sound;
            sound.play();
        }       
    }   
}
```

What's going wrong here?  Many examples online basically use this code, just changing variable names and the like.  I'm using FlashDevelop, in case that makes any difference.  Thanks.

**EDIT**
Apparently it's somehow linked to that file.  I tried Kalimba.mp3, Maid with the Flaxen Hair.mp3, and Sleep Away.mp3, all of which are Windows 7 defaults in Libraries\Music\Sample Music.  None of them worked.  Then I downloaded a random mp3 file elsewhere and tried to use it, and it worked just fine (Blackbird Blackbird - Heartbeat.mp3 from http://www.last.fm/music/+free-music-downloads/sample).  I have tried using converters to make sure Kalimba was at 44100 Hz with a bitrate of 128 kbps, but that didn't seem to work.  What's the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked perfectly for me with your code. Check your mp3 file. Try a different file and see if it works.

Also check for silly mistakes like:

- Have you used addChild() to add instance of Main class? The init() in your Main.as will fire only after you've added it to display list
- Is the pathing in your source correct? I've changed my path to "test.mp3", put your mp3 in a root folder to be sure.

Comment: The Main class shouldn't have to be added through addChild(), from what I understand; it's the point of entry class.  I tried calling stage.addChild(this), just in case though.  The pathing is correct.  I've also tried Maid with the Flaxen Hair.mp3 and Sleep Away.mp3, all three of these coming from the Windows 7 defaults in Libraries\Music\Sample Music.  This morning I moved from FlashDevelop to trying it in Flash Builder 4.6.  Do I have to do anything special with the files or with the path themselves?  Is the file you used something that's easy to get for free online?

Comment: Yeah, you don't need to addChild() if it's the main class. I used a free MP3 sound from some free sound bank. There won't be any difference between FlashDevelop or Flash Builder, the difference might me if you target different Flash SDK.
OK, my second guess is - your mp3 is large, try playing it through a SoundChannel while having an event listener for the COMPLETE event.
If you can, publish the mp3, I want to see it. I'll publish the working code in return.